# how to use variables in KQL?

Tags: variables, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am trying to write a query with variable on KQL.
This is it's 1st part:
[image]

I want to use it in other query to add a column containing a percentage of each event in total number. In other words Percentage = EventNumber / totalEvents.

This is my 2nd query:

[image]

But I am getting an error when I am trying to combine my queries. Can you help my in fixing that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try using `toscalar()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/toscalarfunction

for example:

```
let total_events = toscalar(
    T
    | where Timestamp > ago(7d)
    | count
);
T
| where Timestamp > ago(7d)
| summarize count() by Event
| extend percentage = 100.0 * count_ / total_events
```

in addition, you can materialize the results of a sub-query and re-use them using the `as` operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/asoperator

for example:

```
T
| where Timestamp > ago(7d)
| summarize count() by Event
| as hint.materialized=true TT
| extend percentage = 100.0 * count_ / toscalar(TT | summarize sum(count_))
```